# Repeating label on every page, not header, not tabular, but multicol

Tags: multicol

How can I print repeating label on every page in first column?

The example below, I would like to repeat `\plab` on other pages at the same place.
It is not header actually.

```
\documentclass{article}
\usepackage{multicol}
\usepackage{lipsum}
\usepackage{geometry}
\usepackage{xcolor}
 \geometry{
 a4paper,
 landscape,
 margin=1cm
 }
\newcommand*{\plab}{
{\LARGE label1} \\
\textcolor{gray}{\rule{\columnwidth}{2pt}}
\par
}

\begin{document}
\begin{multicols*}{3}

 \plab
 \lipsum[1-20]

\end{multicols*}
\end{document}
```

EDIT: I found very simmilar need and solution on TEX at 
[How to set one header for each page using multicols](https://tex.stackexchange.com/questions/218587/how-to-set-one-header-for-each-page-using-multicols?rq=1)
But I am not able to make it working in my example, though.

Comment: Shall this label appear in every first column of a page?

Comment: Right, this way. Finaly, I got working the solution from questions 270596, which was answered exactly as I need.

Comment: I think it can be closed as duplicate of 270596.