# Background color in Section titles

Tags: backgrounds, section-titles

I'm still a bit newbie in latex and i'm editing a cheatsheet template that I found with some math formulas and extreme compact form. That is why I want to add a color background to the Sections titles form better reading. I already tried everything I found googling and in latex pages without success.

I managed to locate what I think is the section that I need to change to achieve what I want. My best result was a color backgrounds but with the titles in a new line (the color box was in one line and the title in another) and also the line didn't stop at the column.

https://github.com/blechturm/MITx_capstone_1/blob/master/content/def.tex
This is where I think I need to change some code:

```
\makeatletter % Author: https://tex.stackexchange.com/questions/218587/how-to-set-one-header-for-each-page-using-multicols
\renewcommand{\section}{\@startsection{section}{1}{0mm}%
                                {.2ex}%
                                {.2ex}%x
                                {\color{black}\sffamily\small\bfseries}}
\renewcommand{\subsection}{\@startsection{subsection}{1}{0mm}%
                                {.2ex}%
                                {.2ex}%x
                                {\sffamily\bfseries}}
```

Any help is appreciated!
Regards.

Comment: Does this answer your question? [Giving headlines a background color spanning across the entire typearea](https://tex.stackexchange.com/questions/40034/giving-headlines-a-background-color-spanning-across-the-entire-typearea)

Comment: [This answer](https://tex.stackexchange.com/a/40051/10478) solves your issue using the titlesec package.

Answer (score 1):

It is easier to use `titlesec`. Since you are a bit light on what you want to achieve, I'll just show an example.

```
\documentclass{article}
\usepackage[svgnames]{xcolor}
\usepackage[explicit]{titlesec}


\titleformat{\section}
[display]
{\sffamily\color{black}\small\bfseries}
{}
{0pt}
{\colorbox{Green!30}{\S\thesection. #1}}

\begin{document}
\section{First section}
\section{Second section}

\end{document}
```

[image]

Answer (score 0):

I think I manage to do what I want. Probabibly I'm rewriting the first \section configuration but this works. I tried to write the same inside the first renewcommand but it didnt work.

```
\makeatletter % Author: https://tex.stackexchange.com/questions/218587/how-to-set-one-header-for-each-page-using-multicols
\renewcommand{\section}{\@startsection{section}{1}{0mm}%
                                {.2ex}%
                                {.2ex}%x
                                {\color{black}\sffamily\small\bfseries}
                                }
                                
\renewcommand{\subsection}{\@startsection{subsection}{1}{0mm}%
                                {.2ex}%
                                {.2ex}%x
                                {\sffamily\bfseries}}
\usepackage{titlesec}
\titleformat{name=\section}[block]
  {\color{black}\sffamily\small\bfseries}
  {}
  {0pt}
  {\colorsection}

\newcommand{\colorsection}[1]{%
  \colorbox{yellow}{\parbox{\dimexpr\columnwidth-2\fboxsep-2\fboxrule\relax}{\strut\thesection~#1\strut}}}
```

[image]