# Color Box for Section Title : Titlesec or others soluce explained/commented for beginners

Tags: tikz-pgf, titlesec, section-titles

I try to do with LateX some layout I usually do really easily on Word because I would like to use 100% LaTeX (I would currently describe myself as low intermediate LaTeX user). Here is what I aim to do :

[image]

I already used tikz package to do the rectangular layout (I don't know if it's the best solution since I need to repeat it for each page but anyway).
**Now I would like to get automatically a color box for Sections titles.**

I already checked those two discussions that are relevant to my problem, but ***I can't handle to understand how to control parameters*** such as shape of the text (color, size) and of the color box (color, height, full line or limited to the text).

1. [Giving headlines a background color spanning across the entire typearea](https://tex.stackexchange.com/questions/40034/giving-headlines-a-background-color-spanning-across-the-entire-typearea?newreg=896e9d7d13234dab988c90567839863d)
2. [Background color in Section titles](https://tex.stackexchange.com/questions/565876/background-color-in-section-titles)
3. *titlesec*'s documentation

Especially, I would like

- to be the nearest as possible from the example
- to limit those modifications to Sections only without modifying anything from subsections
- to have something which is automatically scale and "attached" to \section{} which means to avoid to used tikz (which I believe need to draw manually for each section and be moved every time a modification is made and be specified for each section as I do for rectangular layout at each page).

Here is my current try with a solution from the discussion cited below, which seems simpler to understand but is not totally convenient (Size of Section title changes and become smaller than subsection, box is shaped with the text, Parameters can't clearly be controlled).

```
\documentclass[a4paper,12pt]{article}   
\usepackage{lmodern}                    
\usepackage[english]{babel}             
\usepackage[utf8]{inputenc}             
\usepackage[T1]{fontenc}                


\usepackage{amsmath,amsfonts,amssymb,empheq}    
\usepackage{graphicx}                           
\usepackage[svgnames]{xcolor}   
\usepackage{tikz}

\usepackage[explicit,nobottomtitles]{titlesec}

\usepackage[left=1.3cm,right=1.3cm,top=0cm,bottom=2.6cm]{geometry}  % Text Margins
\usepackage{lipsum}                                             
\renewcommand{\thesection}{\Roman{section}.}                    
\pdfinclusioncopyfonts=1

\usepackage{hyperref}
\hypersetup{
    colorlinks=true,
%    linkcolor=RoyalNavyBlue, 
    linkcolor=black,    
    urlcolor=cyan,
    citecolor=black}

\setlength\parindent{0pt} 
\def\arraystretch{2} 
\usepackage{enumitem} 

\usepackage{caption}  

\usepackage{geometry} 


\usepackage{linegoal} 
\usepackage{subcaption}
\usepackage{cleveref}
\captionsetup[subfigure]{subrefformat=simple,labelformat=simple}
\renewcommand\thesubfigure{(\alph{subfigure})}
\usepackage{fancyhdr}       
                            
%%%%%%%%%%%%%%%%%%%%%%%%%%%%%%%%%%%%%%%%%%%%%%%%%%%%%%%%%%%%%%%%%%%%%%%%%%%%%%%%%%%%%%%%%%%
\begin{document}
\begin{tikzpicture}[NavyBlue, remember picture,overlay] % NavyBlue rectangle layout
    \draw[very thick]
        ([yshift=-24pt,xshift=24pt]current page.north west)--
        ([yshift=-24pt,xshift=-24pt]current page.north east)--
        ([yshift=24pt,xshift=-24pt]current page.south east)--
        ([yshift=24pt,xshift=24pt]current page.south west)--cycle;
\end{tikzpicture}
%%%%%%%%%%%%%%%%%%%%%%%%%%%%%%%%%%%%%%%%%%%%%%%%%%%%%%%%%%%%%%%%%%%%%%%%%%%%%%%%%%%%%%%%%%%%%%
\section{Section1}
\subsection{Subsection1}
\subsubsection{Subsection1}
%%%%%%%%%%%%%%%%%%%%%%%%%%%%%%%%%%%%%%%%%%%%%%%%%%%%%%%%%%%%%%%%%%%%%%%%%%%%%%%%%%%%%%%%%%%%%%
\titleformat{\section} % titlesec modification to get color box
{\color{white}\bf}
{}
{0pt}
{\colorbox{NavyBlue}{\thesection. #1}}
%%%%%%%%%%%%%%%%%%%%%%%%%%%%%%%%%%%%%%%%%%%%%%%%%%%%%%%%%%%%%%%%%%%%%%%%%%%%%%%%%%%%%%%%%%%%%%
\tableofcontents
\listoftables 
\listoffigures
\section{Section2}
\subsection{Subsection2}
\subsubsection{Subsection2}
\end{document}
```

***To conclude : If you could please choose one of the solution from the cited linked and adapt it/comment it in a litteraly way so I could manage to adapt it to my objective, I would be really grateful !***