# How to set one header for each page using multicols in 2022

Tags: formatting, header-footer, texlive, templates, multicol

I've used headers like described [here](https://tex.stackexchange.com/questions/218587/how-to-set-one-header-for-each-page-using-multicols?newreg=65f3ca6cb42b4db5bf00899a8644921e) in my documents. However, since TeX Live 2022 this no longer work. Instead of a header getting printed on the page, it seems like all the columns get pushed to the right.

[image: new behavior]

Unfortunately, I don't understand how the original approach even worked and don't know how to fix it. Is there anyone that knows how to achieve this on TeX Live 2022?

Comment: hmm given that post starts "I probably broke something but....." It's done well to last 8 years:-)  I'll have a look....

Comment: it fails in texlive 2021 as wll, OK in 2020

Answer (score 8, accepted):

[image]

The referenced answer patches a few lines into the interal `\multi@column@out`command to add the box.  That command has changed over the years but copying the new code to the answer seems to work.

```
\documentclass[10pt,landscape,a4paper]{article}
\usepackage[utf8]{inputenc}
\usepackage[ngerman]{babel}
\usepackage[utopia,sfscaled]{mathdesign}
%\usepackage[lf,minionint]{MinionPro}
%\renewcommand{\sfdefault}{phv}
%\usepackage[lf]{MyriadPro}
\usepackage{multicol}
\usepackage[top=0mm,bottom=0mm,left=0mm,right=0mm]{geometry}
%\usepackage{hyperref}
\usepackage{lipsum}
\usepackage[framemethod=tikz]{mdframed}
%\usepackage{fancyhdr} ---> ???
\usepackage{microtype}

\renewcommand{\baselinestretch}{.8}
\pagestyle{empty}

\global\mdfdefinestyle{header}{%
linecolor=gray,linewidth=1pt,%
leftmargin=0mm,rightmargin=0mm,skipbelow=0mm,skipabove=0mm,
}

\newcommand{\header}{
\begin{mdframed}[style=header]
\footnotesize
Some Text Inside\\
Page~\thepage~of~6
\end{mdframed}
}

\makeatletter
\renewcommand{\section}{\@startsection{section}{1}{0mm}%
                                {.2ex}%
                                {.2ex}%x
                                {\sffamily\bfseries}}



\def\multi@column@out{%
   \ifnum\outputpenalty <-\@M
   \speci@ls \else
   \ifvoid\colbreak@box\else
     \mult@info\@ne{Re-adding forced
               break(s) for splitting}%
     \setbox\@cclv\vbox{%
        \unvbox\colbreak@box
        \penalty-\@Mv\unvbox\@cclv}%
   \fi
   \splittopskip\topskip
   \splitmaxdepth\@maxdepth
   \boxmaxdepth\@maxdepth
   \dimen@\@colroom
   \divide\skip\footins\col@number
   \ifvoid\footins \else
      \leave@mult@footins
   \fi
   \ifvbox \@kludgeins
     \advance \dimen@ -\ht\@kludgeins
     \ifdim \wd\@kludgeins>\z@
        \shr@nkingtrue
     \fi
   \fi
   \process@cols\mult@firstbox{%
%%%%% START CHANGE
\ifnum\count@=\numexpr\mult@rightbox+2\relax
          \setbox\count@\vsplit\@cclv to \dimexpr \dimen@-1cm\relax
\setbox\count@\vbox to \dimen@{\vbox to 1cm{\header}\unvbox\count@\vss}%
\else
      \setbox\count@\vsplit\@cclv to \dimen@
\fi
%%%%% END CHANGE
            \set@keptmarks
            \setbox\count@
                 \vbox to\dimen@
                  {\unvbox\count@
                   \ifshr@nking
                    \vfilmaxdepth\fi}%
           }%
   \setbox\mult@rightbox
       \vsplit\@cclv to\dimen@
   \set@keptmarks
   \setbox\mult@rightbox\vbox to\dimen@
          {\unvbox\mult@rightbox
           \ifshr@nking\vfilmaxdepth\fi}%
   \ifvoid\@cclv \else
       \unvbox\@cclv
       \ifnum\outputpenalty=\@M
       \else
          \penalty\outputpenalty
       \fi
       \ifvoid\footins\else
         \PackageWarning{multicol}%
          {I moved some lines to
           the next page.\MessageBreak
           Footnotes on page
           \thepage\space might be wrong}%
       \fi
       \ifnum \c@tracingmulticols>\thr@@
                    \hrule\allowbreak \fi
   \fi
   \ifx\@empty\kept@firstmark
      \let\firstmark\kept@topmark
      \let\botmark\kept@topmark
   \else
      \let\firstmark\kept@firstmark
      \let\botmark\kept@botmark
   \fi
   \let\topmark\kept@topmark
   \mult@info\tw@
        {Use kept top mark:\MessageBreak
          \meaning\kept@topmark
         \MessageBreak
         Use kept first mark:\MessageBreak
          \meaning\kept@firstmark
        \MessageBreak
         Use kept bot mark:\MessageBreak
          \meaning\kept@botmark
        \MessageBreak
         Produce first mark:\MessageBreak
          \meaning\firstmark
        \MessageBreak
        Produce bot mark:\MessageBreak
          \meaning\botmark
         \@gobbletwo}%
   \boxmaxdepth\maxdimen
   \setbox\@cclv\vbox{\unvbox\partial@page
                      \page@sofar}%
   \@makecol\@outputpage
     \global\let\kept@topmark\botmark
     \global\let\kept@firstmark\@empty
     \global\let\kept@botmark\@empty
     \mult@info\tw@
        {(Re)Init top mark:\MessageBreak
         \meaning\kept@topmark
         \@gobbletwo}%
   \global\@colroom\@colht
   \global \@mparbottom \z@
   \global \@textfloatsheight \z@
   \process@deferreds
   \@whilesw\if@fcolmade\fi{\@outputpage
      \global\@colroom\@colht
      \process@deferreds}%
   \mult@info\@ne
     {Colroom:\MessageBreak
      \the\@colht\space
              after float space removed
              = \the\@colroom \@gobble}%
    \set@mult@vsize \global
  \fi}

\makeatother
\setlength{\parindent}{0pt}

\begin{document}
\footnotesize
\begin{multicols*}{5}
\lipsum\lipsum\lipsum\lipsum
\lipsum\lipsum\lipsum\lipsum
\end{multicols*}
\end{document}
```

Comment: Maybe make it more robust using `\patchcmd` or the like?

Comment: @Skillmon not sure it  would have been more robust: it would probably just have given a fail to patch error. Also random one-off aswers are not guaranted stable for a decade of use:-)